# Testing controller methods

Tags: php, phpunit

How do I test controller methods? Having a test:

```
class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase {

   //...

   public function testActionDoSomething() {
      $this -> assertEquals(DAO :: getFromTableById(1), 0);
      $fooController = new FooController();
      $fooController -> actionDoSomething();
      $this -> assertEquals(DAO :: getFromTableById(1), 1);
   }

}
```

What if the method requires HTTP parameters? How do I pass them inside the test method?

Comment: Is your application built using a framework? If yes, many people will likely had your same issue and there's for sure a module out there that can help you.

Comment: No, I'm asking about a custom application in MVC.

Comment: Because as far as I can see it, there's no point in testing anything else beside controllers, as they're the only endpoint that users can invoke.

Comment: I don't agree. Testing controller is not unit testing. With unit tests you want to ensure that the behavior of small logic units (methods) with clear responsibilities doesn't change by mistake while developing. If you test controllers (without mocking everything below) you're making huge test cases and you're testing a big part of the application. What you're trying to achieve is usually done with Selenium tests

Comment: If you could provide an example of controller you are going to test, that would be great